# parse a url response(serialized data) to php array

Tags: php, serialization

What I want to achieve is unserialize all the data I am getting from the below link and get it converted to php array

http://ip-api.com/php

I know I can use unserialize() function of php and pass the serialized string to get it converted.
how can I convert the response of above link to php array ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generally use curl to get the content from external link

Do the following

```
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://ip-api.com/php');
$contents = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
print_r(unserialize($contents));
```

your result array will look like below

> Array ( [query] => 43.231.208.107 [region] => [timezone] => Asia/Kathmandu [org] => ClassicTech Pvt. [as] => AS55915 Classic Tech Pvt. Ltd. [city] => Kathmandu (Koteshwor) [zip] => [isp] => ClassicTech Pvt. [status] => success [lat] => 27.684499740601 [lon] => 85.34839630127 [country] => Nepal [countryCode] => NP [regionName] => Central Region )

also you can create a function and pass the url if you like to clean up the code.

Comment: will it work on the localhost or I have to upload the script on live server to work? I am not getting any response on my local server. getting blank page and nothing else

Comment: the issue was with `curl_close($c);` I removed this line and now it works fine. thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `file_get_contents()` to archive this.

```
$result = file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/php');
var_dump(unserialize($result));
```